# Vidyo.io javascript connection is failing from localhost

Tags: javascript, vidyo

Tried the Vidyo angular [tutorial](http://vidyo.io/blog/how-to/using-angularjs-webrtc-build-group-video-chat-app-vidyo-io/). Followed all the steps but at last when I call connect method it fail's

```
  $rootScope.vidyoConnector.Connect({
    host: "prod.vidyo.io",// or using given host on my dashboard
    token: 'TOKEN',
    displayName: "demo",
    resourceId: "demoroom",
    onSuccess:  ()=> {
      // successful connection
      console.log("successful connection");
    },
    onFailure:  (reason)=> {
      // failed to connect, check reason to find out why
      console.log(reason);

    },
    onDisconnected:  (reason)=> {
      console.log('disc', reason);
      //  disconnected, this can be user triggered as well as error case

    }
   }).then((status) => {
    if (status) {
      console.error("ConnectCall pass",status);

    } else {
      console.error("ConnectCall Failed",status);
    }
  }).catch((err) => {

    console.error("ConnectCall Failed",err);
  });
```

https://vio-webrtc-sm001-prod-gcp-ap-sgp-a.prod.vidyo.io/transport

**Payload**

```
{
    "destination":"VidyoClient",
     "data":"VidyoConnectorConnect?c=25636624&host=sandbox.vidyo.io&token= <MYTOKEN>&displayName=demo&resourceId=demoroom",
    "requestNum":2,
    "session":"bdd25a3438d1"
}
```

**response :**

```
{"result":"ok","data":{"retValue":false}}
```

Can't find the usage logs for this on my Vidyo dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your payload: host=sandbox.vidyo.io
The correct one should be: host=prod.vidyo.io